# Elliptic integral as quantity associated with Riemann surface?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, riemann-surfaces, theta-functions

There are many elliptic integrals, so to show my point let me
just pick one of them (complete elliptic integral of the first
kind [1]):

$$K(k) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac {dx} {\sqrt{(1-x^{2})(1-k^{2}x^{2})}}$$

A beautiful solution [1] to this is given by the third Jacobi
theta function $\theta_{3}$:

$$K(k) = \frac{\pi}{2} \theta_{3}^{2}(q)$$

for some function $q = q(k)$.

This means that $K(k)$ enjoys some sort of modularity after some
clever transformation! And whenever I see a function with (near)
modularity, I wonder if it's a function (or a section) on the moduli
space of elliptic curves.

**Question**: Given $k$, can you construct a Riemann surface $\Sigma(k)$
and interpret $K(k)$ as some quantity related to $\Sigma(k)$ (e.g. a period or some sort) so that
the modularity of $K(k)$ is a direct corollary? It would be even
better if such $\Sigma(k)$ is the surface defined by

$$y^{2} = (1-x^{2})(1-k^{2}x^{2}).$$

#### Related

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441501/how-does-one-express-jacobi-theta-functions-in-terms-of-elliptic-integrals

#### Reference

- [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Comment: For those like me who want to look it up: $q= \exp\bigl(-\pi\, K(\sqrt{1-k^2})/K(k)\bigr)$.